# Turbine stream double port binding issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, cloud-foundry, turbine

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4 and Spring Cloud Dalston SR4 to stand up a Turbine server on Cloud Foundry and aggregate my application Hystrix streams. In addition I want to add Spring Boot Actuator monitoring and management to the Turbine server. I realize there is ample documentation on how to do this in a local environment and I do have it working locally. However it is a different matter when deploying to Cloud Foundry where I cannot use port numbers in a Url binding.

The issue is that the Turbine stream is provided by an RxNetty server on one port and the Actuator endpoints are provided by via Tomcat on another port. In Cloud Foundry I can only bind my Url to RxNetty endpoint or the Tomcat endpoint, not both.

No combination of management.port and turbine.stream.port allows me to access the turbine stream and the actuator endpoints from one host binding. The following is an example of what I would expect to be able to do:-

https://myapp.mydomain.com/info (to report actuator info details)
https://myapp.mydomain.com/turbine.stream (to stream turbine metrics)

**Note:** There are no port numbers in these Urls.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible on CF with boot 1.5.x and Dalston or Edgware. It will be with boot 2.0 and Finchley.

Comment: Is there anything special I would need to do in Boot 2.0 or will it work out of the box.

Comment: Netty has first-class support in boot 2.0. It will listen on server.port and have normal actuator behavior.

Comment: @specergibb not that you need it but if you wanted it you could post these comments as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just getting back to this now. As noted by spencergibb, moving to springboot 2.0 and cloud Finchley works.

Answer (score 0):

Requests to your app on Cloud Foundry go through the Cloud Foundry Go Router, which uses the http host header to direct traffic to all the container instances running your app. The http based gorouter expecter only one port to be opened by the app to forward http traffic to. However, the gorouter also support tcp routing which should allow you to have multiple ports open. see the [docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#http-vs-tcp-routes)for an explanation of tcp vs. http routes on cloud foundry.

If you are running on Pivotal Cloud Foundry you can use the Circuit Breaker Dashboard provided by Spring Cloud Serviecs for PCF then you won't need to setup the turbine stream. The Spring Cloud Services Dashboard uses RabbitMQ instead of SSE events see [SCS docs](http://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-5/common/index.html) for details

Comment: I have done some reading on the TCP routing you suggested. However it's not clear to me what defines a TCP application. Are you saying that either of the 2 HTTP endpoints (Turbine/Actuator) can function on a tcp route as opposed to a HTTP route? Also I am running on a managed on-prem instance of PCF so Spring Cloud Services are not an option for me.

Comment: Nevermind, I see @spencergibb has answered that what I'm attempting is not yet possible.